# Can't launch android google drive app with programatically pre-selected account

Tags: android, android-intent, google-drive-api

I'm developing an android app and I want to launch the Google Drive app from within my app. I can do this successfully with the code below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.docs");        
startActivity(intent);
```

However, I have multiple accounts on the phone and I want to be able to programatically pre-select the active account for Google Drive to use during when launched.
My app already has Google Sign-In credentials and the Google Drive scope stored in mCredential. I have tried adding this to the intent:

```
intent.putExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME,Credential.getSelectedAccountName());
```

...but it doesn't work.

Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I did some research on how to get the account using intent. Unfortunately, '*AccountPicker*' is the only way to retrieve the account. For this task, the Google Play Services library provides a convinient account picker dialog you can invoke using AccountPicker. In order to use the API, you must include Google Play services library with your project.

Below Code is a sample implementation on how to retrieve an account:

```
 protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int     resultCode,
 final Intent data) {
 if (requestCode == SOME_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
 String accountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
 }
 }
```

For more information regarding AccountPicker, follow link below:
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/AccountPicker

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get the account name in some situations, you can (fortunately) get it with `getSignInResultFromIntent ()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

    GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent (intent);
    GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount ();

    acct.getEmail () // your e-mail

}
```